# In Jmeter, Summary Report: Maximum Response Time and jp@gc-Response Codes Per Second total time taken Are they same?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, stress-testing, jmeter-maven-plugin

In Summary Report **Maximum Response Time** was 538ms which means all the execution was done and its maximum response time was 538ms.

But in **jp@gc-Response Codes Per Second** we can see that total time of execution was 9 seconds. So now I assume that total time of execution and all the responses for that execution to be done with in 9 seconds.So max response time according to **jp@gc-Response Codes Per Second** is 9 seconds

Both result are different. So I would like to know how the maximum response time is calculated in summary report and can we consider **jp@gc-Response Codes Per Second** total time taken to get response as maximum response time.

Summary Report: Maximum Response Time and **jp@gc-Response Codes Per Second** total time taken
Are they same ??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FpIc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not the same.

- Maximum Response Time in the summary report is the biggest value of the response time recorded during the duration of the test, i.e. it indicates single slowest request
- Response Codes Per Second shows **concurrency** per response code, i.e. how many requests were executed during this particular second of the test execution.

In your case:

- all responses were having [HTTP Status Code 200](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200)
- maximum throughput was 38 requests per second between 5th and 6th duration of the test
- maximum response time for a single request was 538 ms

More information:

- [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)
- [Understanding Your Reports: Part 1 - What are KPIs?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-kpis-part-1-what-are-kpis)